# about nodejs async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

i'm learning nodejs, here is my confusion:

enviroment:

- os:windows
- nodejs: v18.19.0

code:

```js
const sleep = (seconds) => {
  const milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
};
async function task1() {
  console.log("task1 doing");
  await sleep(1);
  console.log("task1 done");
}
async function task2() {
  console.log("task2");
}
task1().then(() => {
  console.log(1);
});

task2().then(() => {
  console.log(2);
});
```

my expect output is:

```bash
task1 doing
task1 done
1
task2
2
```

but the real output is:

```bash
task1 doing
task2
2
task1 done
1
```

it means that when call func task1 it breaked before `await sleep(1)`  then it call task2?

use follow code , i can call task1 and task2 in order

```js
async function callTask() {
  await task1();
  await task2();
}
callTask()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("All tasks completed.");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
  });
```

the output is

```bash
task1 doing
task1 done
task2
All tasks completed.
```

i have confusion about the different between `then` and `await` .

Comment: There's probably a good duplicate I haven't found yet which goes into more technical detail.  But "the difference between `then` and `await`" is they're two different things that accomplish different tasks.  They are in no way a replacement for each other.  Adding a `.then()` callback basically means "when the task is finished sometime later, do this other thing sometime afterward".  It doesn't stop the code from continuing to the next statement.  Using `await` basically means "don't do anything else until this task is finished".  It *does* stop the code from continuing to the next statement.

Comment: Don't mix `async/await` with `.then()/.catch()`. They work fine, separate or in any combination, but the code becomes difficult to understand. Stick to `async/await` and combine it with `try/catch` for exceptions and everything will become more clear.

Comment: You're not `await`ing `task1` before you start `task2`. You're only doing something _when_ `task1` ends (`then`). While `task1` isn't doing anything (while it sleeps), `task2` can run. You did not tie the end of `task1` to the start of `task2`, they're not causally linked.